# PHP (Search function) If values in 2 arrays match, store this array

Tags: php, arrays, search, compare, match

i want to create a simple search function with an input field where the user can search messages, stored in the database, by tags.

The problem is that the function returns ALL messages and not the one where the tags match.

Here is my try:

```
  public function getMatches($tagsGiven) {
  $mergedTagArray = array();
  $messageToTag = array();

  $messageRepo = $this->messageRepository->findAll(); // all messages from DB

  $messageTagsArray = explode(',', $tagsGiven); // tags given by the user

  foreach ($messageRepo as $oMessage) {
    $messageTag = $oMessage->getMessageTags(); // get tags from all messages   
    $storeTagsUnseri = unserialize($messageTag); // unserialize tags given by the user

    if (!in_array($messageTagsArray,$storeTagsUnseri)) {  //if tags from user matches tags from DB messages
      $messageToTag[] = $oMessage->getMessageText();     // get the message text from the DB message and store it in array
    }
  }
  return $messageToTag;     // return all message texts matching
}
```

}

Thank you very much!

Best regards

**EDIT**

```
if (array_intersect($messageTagsArray,$storeTagsUnseri)) {}
```

That did the trick.

Comment: you are checking if object is not in array. !in_array($messageTagsArray,$storeTagsUnseri). if you are not expecting multidimensional array you can simply do $array = (array) $object;

Comment: I don't really understand what you mean. :(

Comment: $storeTagsUnseri = unserialize($messageTag);
$storeTagsUnseri = (array)($storeTagsUnseri);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok as I mantioned in my comment you are trying to see if object is not in array. You can't do it like that, you have to convert your object to arrat first. So add this to your code if you dont expect multidimensional array:

```
 $storeTagsUnseri = unserialize($messageTag);
 $storeTagsUnseri = (array)($storeTagsUnseri);
```

or just do:

```
 $json  = json_encode($storeTagsUnseri);
 $$storeTagsUnseriarray = json_decode($json, true);
```

And than do [array_intersect()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect.php)

Comment: Thank you. But i can't see any difference in my var_dumb. It still returns all the messages not the one i want..:(

Comment: yeah glad you solved it with array_intersect(). I edited my answer in case somebody has similar problem

Answer (score 0):

You need to let the db do the processing for you.

```
   SELECT message FROM YourDB WHERE message like '%tagName%'
```

Comment: I can not really work with the DB here. It's extbase. There have to be another way.